# Convertir string a objeto o array en PHP

Tags: php, json

Este *string* te lo devuelve al enviar los datos a un proveedor:

```
string(474) "
{
     "status":"success",
     "Data":
        {
        "RazonSocial":"Ferreteria Perez",
        "RFC":"XAXX010101006",
        "Calle":"Av.Juarez",
        "Numero":"1234",
        "Interior":"",
        "Colonia":"Centro",
        "CodigoPostal":"44640",
        "Ciudad":"Guadalajara",
        "Delegacion":"Guadalajara",
        "Estado":"Jalisco",
        Pais":"M\u00e9xico",
        "Contacto":{
              "Nombre":"Jos\u00e9 Ram\u00f3n",
              "Apellidos":"P\u00e9rezL\u00f3pez",
              "Email":"josepe@mail.co",
              "Email2":"",
              "Email3":"",
              "Telefono":"33 3877 0000"},
              "UID":"5bbecdf98df8c",
              "cfdis":0,
              "cuentas_banco":[]
        }
    }"
```

Quisiera convertirlo a un array o a un objeto. De la respuesta solo me interesa:

```
"UID":"5bbecdf98df8c"
```

Y:

```
"status":"success",
```

Ya lo he intentado y no puedo convertirlo con PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considero que para tu caso, nos podemos quedar con el JSON directamente, ya que al pasar `TRUE` el objeto original es reconvertido a array. Estaríamos hablando entonces de **una segunda conversión innecesaria**.

Además, el código se escribe de una forma más elegante (a mi juicio):

```
$string ='{
 "status":"success",
 "Data":
    {
    "RazonSocial":"Ferreteria Perez",
    "RFC":"XAXX010101006",
    "Calle":"Av.Juarez",
    "Numero":"1234",
    "Interior":"",
    "Colonia":"Centro",
    "CodigoPostal":"44640",
    "Ciudad":"Guadalajara",
    "Delegacion":"Guadalajara",
    "Estado":"Jalisco",
    "Pais":"M\u00e9xico",
    "Contacto":{
          "Nombre":"Jos\u00e9 Ram\u00f3n",
          "Apellidos":"P\u00e9rezL\u00f3pez",
          "Email":"josepe@mail.co",
          "Email2":"",
          "Email3":"",
          "Telefono":"33 3877 0000"
    },
    "UID":"5bbecdf98df8c",
    "cfdis":0,
    "cuentas_banco":[]
  }
}';


$json = json_decode($string);
echo $json->status;
echo $json->Data->UID;
```

**Salida:**

```
success
5bbecdf98df8c
```

Comment: Realmente no existe una *reconversión a array* (no existe doble conversión o conversión posterior). En cuanto a rendimiento podría ser justo lo contrario, generar un objeto resta rendimiento a la función debido a las acciones adicionales que deben llevarse a cabo para ello ([ver código fuente](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/json/json_parser.tab.c#L1882)), pero te apoyo en que es mejor trabajar con los datos originales y no con una conversión a matriz que tergiverse el contenido y estructura original.

Comment: @OscarGarcia gracias por tu comentario. Revisando bien el código fuente puede verse claramente que hay manipulaciones suplementarias cuando se pasa el parámetro `TRUE`. El objeto se crearía realmente en  [`php_json_parser_object_create`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/json/json_parser.tab.c#L1869), y cuando se pasa el parámetro `TRUE` lo que ocurre es **una actualización del objeto ya creado** en [`php_json_parser_object_update`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/json/json_parser.tab.c#L1879). Es al menos lo que yo puedo interpretar.

Answer (score 2):

A `Pais` (`Pais":"M\u00e9xico",`) le falta una `"` al principio para ser un json correcto.

Usa [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode):

```
<?php
 $string ='{
 "status":"success",
 "Data":
    {
    "RazonSocial":"Ferreteria Perez",
    "RFC":"XAXX010101006",
    "Calle":"Av.Juarez",
    "Numero":"1234",
    "Interior":"",
    "Colonia":"Centro",
    "CodigoPostal":"44640",
    "Ciudad":"Guadalajara",
    "Delegacion":"Guadalajara",
    "Estado":"Jalisco",
    "Pais":"M\u00e9xico",
    "Contacto":{
          "Nombre":"Jos\u00e9 Ram\u00f3n",
          "Apellidos":"P\u00e9rezL\u00f3pez",
          "Email":"josepe@mail.co",
          "Email2":"",
          "Email3":"",
          "Telefono":"33 3877 0000"
    },
    "UID":"5bbecdf98df8c",
    "cfdis":0,
    "cuentas_banco":[]
  }
}';


$array = json_decode($string, true);
var_dump($array['status'],$array['Data']['UID']);
```

---

**Salida:**

```
string(7) "success"
string(13) "5bbecdf98df8c"
```

El `true` como segundo parámetro lo decodifica como array, sino te da un objeto.

Comment: Gracias @alo realmente lo intente

Comment: No deberías aconsejar malas costumbres, como la de forzar la conversión del JSON a una matriz multidimensional. Es mejor (y recomendable) trabajar con los tipos de datos tal cual provienen de origen.

Comment: @OscarGarcia no veo donde "estoy aconsejando", lo que sea mejor y "recomendable" dependerá de la aplicación, el uso de los datos, la versión de php, etc...

Comment: Te pido disculpas, siento haber escrito "recomendado" en vez de "alentado" o "inducido". Lo que sí que no llego a entender es qué tiene que ver la versión de PHP o el uso de datos para que sea mejor y "recomendable" hacer la conversión a matriz. ¿Podrías ponerme un ejemplo ilustrativo? Gracias.

Comment: En este caso usé vardump y array pues el "problema" pareciera ser una `"` faltante, y englobar todo el string con `"` dobles en vez de simples. salvados esos detalles: el "string" representa un `json`, por lo general se usa `json_decode`, si se quiere como `array` u `objeto` se usa el segundo parámetro, en mi opinión resulta mas didáctico ponerlo explícito. En php los arrays históricamente son más rápidos de acceder que objetos o clases, en las últimas versiones la diferencia se reduce (arrays ocupan un poco mas de memoria) por eso depende que tipo de tratamiento posterior tengan los datos.

Comment: Cierto, las preferencias y capacidades personales tienen un peso muy importante a la hora de decidir un tipo de dato u otro. También alguien podría decir que si se va a iterar con `foreach` también es más cómodo con una matriz, pero en realidad el comportamiento sería exactamente el mismo. El cuanto al rendimiento y uso de memoria hoy en día lo pondría tras legibilidad del código en orden de importancia a la hora de trabajar con un valor obtenido en JSON.

Comment: El +1 te lo di principalmente por haber descubierto rápidamente el error en el JSON.

Comment: el tema legibilidad es también dependiente del proyecto si se utiliza más de un lenguaje (y la penalización entre usar objetos con -> o arrays con [] es mínima/aceptable) la segunda forma (usar corchetes englobando keys o propiedades) resulta visualmente más políglota.